# how to retrieve value of dropdown selection when form is not been submitted yet

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have following code

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.IDs, new SelectList(Model. IDs), Model.SelectedID)
}
```

So user selection from this combo bind to `SelectedID` property of the model. My understanding is that this binding happen only when form is submitted. Let’s say from the same page, I need to do an AJAX call but at this point ) `Model.SelectedID` does not provide any value because form hasn’t been submitted yet (although user has selected something from drop down). Any ideas how to best deal with this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use javascript.

```
var selectedValue = $("#IDs").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

bind a `change` event to your DD

```
$("#DDL_ID").change(function(){

var currVal = $(this).val();

//do ajax

});
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed you would get this value with javascript on the change of the drop down list.

I wanted to point out however, that your understanding of the overload you are using for the drop down list is incorrect. This [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703561.aspx) will display a default option box label.

For example you could prompt the users to select select something from the list:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.IDs, new SelectList(Model. IDs), "Select Something...")
```

If you were to post the form in your example as is, you can see the selected item come across in the form. If your view model is setup in such a fashion the model binder would take over and bind this value to your "SelectedID" property.

```
[HttpPost]
public string DropDown(FormCollection form)
{
    var selectedItem = form["IDs"];
    return selectedItem;
}
```